# java.lang.NullPointerException when accessing inner class field

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer exception from the code below at line 19,`seq[index].value = lo;`. The sequence class has a value field with integer type, but I think the problem is to access the array of seq instance.

```
public class ImprovedFibonacci {

class Sequence{
    int value = 0;
    boolean isEven = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    final int MAX_LOOP = 20;
    int lo = 1;
    int hi = 1;
    int i = 0;
    String mark = "-";

    int index = 0;
    ImprovedFibonacci.Sequence[] seq = new ImprovedFibonacci.Sequence[MAX_LOOP];
    seq[index].value = lo;

    System.out.println("Fibonacci seq 1 : " + lo);
    System.out.println("Sequence class index: "+index+"value: "+seq[index].value);

    for(i=MAX_LOOP;i>=1;i--) {
        hi = hi + lo;
        lo = hi - lo;
        index++;
        if(hi % 2 == 0){
            mark = "-";
            seq[index].isEven = true;
        }else{
            mark = "";
        }

        System.out.println(i + " : " + hi + mark);
        seq[index].value = hi;
        System.out.println("Sequence class index: "+index+"value: "+seq[index].value+"IsEven: "+seq[index].isEven);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You create array, but never fill with objects.

```
ImprovedFibonacci.Sequence[] seq = new ImprovedFibonacci.Sequence[MAX_LOOP];
    seq[index].value = lo;
```

So seq[index] returns null, and null.value gives you a NullPointerException

For instance:

```
Object[] array = new Object[10];
```

it's create array with 10 elements but every element will be null.

Here is sample code: 
http://ideone.com/0gIYm

Answer (score 1):

`seq` is an array with MAX_LOOP space, but nothing has been instantiated in it.  The first element (`seq[0]`) is null, as are all other elements.

```
seq[index] = new ImprovedFibonacci.Sequence();
seq[index].value = lo;
```

Comment: I understand why it gets null exception. How do I create instances of all array object? If I do that above, I get the following error, Description Resource Path Location Type
No enclosing instance of type ImprovedFibonacci is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ImprovedFibonacci (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ImprovedFibonacci). ImprovedFibonacci.java